# How to convert RectangleF[] into NSArray of CGRects?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, core-graphics

I'm sure I have done it before but I don't find how to: I have a binding here that expects an `NSArray`. The contents are `CGRect` objects.

How do I get an `NSArray` of `CGRect` from an array of `RectangleF[]`?

The other thing I have to convert is: `PointF[][]` into an `NSArray of CGPoint[]

Note that I'm  actually facing a bindings problem here:

```
/// Coordinates for highlight annotation (boxed CGRect's)
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *rects;

/// Array of lines (which is a array of CGPoint's)
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *lines;
```

This is what they currently are:

```
[Export ("rects")]
NSArray Rects { get; set; }

[Export ("lines")]
NSArray Lines { get; set; }
```

This is what won't compile (in the bindings project):

```
[Export ("rects")]
RectangleF[] Rects { get; set; }

[Export ("lines")]
PointF[][] Lines { get; set; }
```

**EDIT/SOLUTION:**

Following PouPou's recommendations, I came up with the following working code.
To convert an array of array of PointF into an NSArray, I implemted this method. Note that its input is actually an AnnotationPoint but that gets converted into PointF:

```
/// <summary>
/// Extends AnnotationPoint[][] to allow conversion into an NSArray containing arrays of CGPoint.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>the NSArray</returns>
/// <param name='aStrokePath'>the path to convert</param>
public static NSArray ToPSPDFInkLines(this AnnotationPoint[][] aStrokePath)
{
    List<NSArray> aLines = new List<NSArray>();
    foreach ( AnnotationPoint[] aLine in aStrokePath )
    {
        List<NSObject> aLinePoints = new List<NSObject>();
        foreach (AnnotationPoint oPoint in aLine)
        {
            aLinePoints.Add(NSObject.FromObject(oPoint.ToPointF()));
        }
        var oNSLineArray = NSArray.FromNSObjects(aLinePoints.ToArray());
        aLines.Add(oNSLineArray);
    }
    NSArray oNSArray = NSArray.FromNSObjects(aLines.ToArray());
    return oNSArray;
}
```

To convert the RectangleF[] into NSArray, this is what I went for. Note that here, I'm working with AnnotationRegion objects but they get converted into RectangleF:

```
NSObject[] aRects = oHighlightAnnot.Coords.Select(oRegion => NSObject.FromObject(oRegion.ToRectangleF())).ToArray();
NSArray oNSArray = NSArray.FromNSObjects(aRects);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CoreGraphic's type`CGRect` is mapped to System.Drawing's `RectangleF` in MonoTouch. When writing bindings you write the later (in C#) when you see the former (in ObjectiveC).

**EDIT** However the binding generator cannot convert `NSArray` into arrays of non-`NSObject` (e.g. value types like `RectangleF`). In such case you can bind them as `NSArray` and mark them with `[Internal]` then provide a better (manual) overload for public consumption.

Then you can create your own `Rectangle[]`, based on the size of the `NSArray`, then iterate the `NSArray` elements to get the elements. You'll need to convert (see `NSObject` and `NSValue` helpers) each element to a `RectangleF`.

Also you **need** to keep `NSArray` when you do not know what types you'll get.

Comment: Hm...this answer is contrary to what Rolf wrote here. Now I'm all puzzled and stuck...http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/1633#Comment_1633 - I'll update my question here.

Comment: Can you please include how I will set my RectangleF[] and PointF[][] into the corresponding NSArrays to use them with the bindings?

Comment: I'll keep the NSArray, but when using NSArray.FromObjects() to populate(!) the NSArray I get: System.ArgumentException: Do not know how to marshal object of type 'System.Drawing.RectangleF[]' to an NSObject
  at MonoTouch.Foundation.NSArray.FromObjects (System.Object[] items) [0x0002c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/shared/Foundation/NSArray.cs:69

Comment: `NSArray.FromObjects` is to create an `NSArray` (reverse from above) and calls `NSObject.FromObject` which has support for `RectangleF`. OTOH your original `NSArray` contains `NSObject` instances that are not `RectangleF` - at least not before being converted. Hard to say without seeing the actual input.

Comment: That's exactly what I want: CREATE an NSArray from RectangleF[] and then ASSIGN that NSArray to binding method and that is throwing the exception. If I manually wrap each RectangleF into an NSObject and then use FromNSObjects() it is working. Bug?

Comment: Bug ? maybe, but it's mostly a loop -> **Hard to say without seeing the actual input.**

Comment: `NSArray.FromObject` accepts a `params object[]` which, depending on how it's used, might be interpreted as a single `RectangleF[]` parameter instead of several `RectangleF` parameters (like it's expected to be used)