# How to convert NSRect/CGRect back to RectangleF in MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

*(This question if the opposite of what I asked before, when going to way from RectangleF[] to NSArray. See here: [How to convert RectangleF[] into NSArray of CGRects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13702264/how-to-convert-rectanglef-into-nsarray-of-cgrects))*

I have a 3rd party library and bindings for it.
One of the bindings is returning an NSArray (note: it is **NOT** an "`NSArray*`" but a plain "`NSArray`"), therefore returning `RectangleF[]` instead of `NSArray` is not working/supported by MonoTouch.
The problem I have now: How to convert the returned `NSArray` (of `NSRect`, that I know) back into an `RectangleF[]`?

If I loop through the NSArray:

```
for(uint i = 0; i < oHighlightAnnot.Rects.Count; ++i)
{
  IntPtr ptrRect = oHighlightAnnot.Rects.ValueAt(i);
  var oObj = new NSObject(ptrRect);
}
```

And inspect oObj, I can see in the debugger that it is an NSRect:

> {NSRect: {{121.3672, 265.76123}, {192.09813, 288}}}

But what then? `NSRect` is not exposed, neither is `CGRect` and `RectangleF` is not inheriting from `NSObject`. How to cast/convert back?

Heres the method for completion:

```
public virtual NSArray Rects
{
    [Export ("rects")]
    get
    {
        NSArray nSArray;
        if (this.IsDirectBinding)
        {
            nSArray = (NSArray)Runtime.GetNSObject (Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSend (base.get_Handle (), PSPDFHighlightAnnotation.selRects));
        }
        else
        {
            nSArray = (NSArray)Runtime.GetNSObject (Messaging.IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper (base.get_SuperHandle (), PSPDFHighlightAnnotation.selRects));
        }
        base.MarkDirty ();
        this.__mt_Rects_var = nSArray;
        return nSArray;
    }
    [Export ("setRects:")]
    set
    {
        if (this.IsDirectBinding)
        {
            Messaging.void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr (base.get_Handle (), PSPDFHighlightAnnotation.selSetRects_, (value != null) ? value.get_Handle () : IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        else
        {
            Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr (base.get_SuperHandle (), PSPDFHighlightAnnotation.selSetRects_, (value != null) ? value.get_Handle () : IntPtr.Zero);
        }
        base.MarkDirty ();
        this.__mt_Rects_var = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*This has been answered [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/1744/#Comment_1744), but just for the record:*

My guess is that you're seeing an NSRect wrapped in an NSValue.

Try this:

```cs
for(uint i = 0; i < oHighlightAnnot.Rects.Count; ++i)
{
    IntPtr ptrRect = oHighlightAnnot.Rects.ValueAt(i);
    var val = new NSValue(ptrRect);
    var rect = val.RectangleFValue;
}
```